# Web based weekly planner

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm looking to implement a web based weekly planner where a user can set when they will be unavailable to work. The state of the week will be saved as a 'varbinary' with a length of 168 which will represent every hour of everyday of a week. The database only needs to store the value of one week as the times unavailable to work will be the same each week. I'm looking for a quick and effective method, possibly based on jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are are asking here, but to learn "*quickly*" about how to use JQuery with ASP.NET MVC I would recommend watching this TekPub video series:

http://tekpub.com/preview/jquery
"Mastering jQuery walks through the basics of using jQuery, the revolutionary JavaScript framework that makes writing client-side code fun and easy, and then dives into the details of writing AJAX enabled ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Forms applications. We will also cover popular plugins and extending jQuery in future episodes."

It will be enough to get you started and the JQuery docs (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and JQuery UI docs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/) should be able to handle the rest.

I believe a JQuery/MVC stack will work great for the project you described.